# How to find the location of .gitattributes on Github.com?

Tags: github, gitattributes

Where can I find `.gitattributes` file on GitHub website or in my repository? I don't use git command line and use website for all uploads. Recently I have posted a SQLite file along with a Python file but in languages it is showing only Python.

Answer (score 1):

Before you read my answer, kindly check https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

It effectively tells you that you either have a file of **.git/info/attributes** or you might have a **.gitattributes** file somewhere.

You can search for any files (including **.gitattributes**) via clicking on the Go To File button

[image]

and then typing in the file you are searching for (**.gitattributes** in this case):

[image]

If you find your file, good! If not, then you will need (sorry **!**) to clone your project and check whether there is a **.git/info/attributes/** file and see whether there are any attributes that are contradicting your aim. You can create a **.gitattributes** file (if it doesn't exist) in your root folder and `git push` it.